# Android intellij IDEA 11 merge assets directory when using library modules

Tags: android, module, intellij-idea

I have an Android project(A) that uses one library module(B) in Intellij IDEA 11. In the main module(A) I have a database file into assets directory and it's working fine.

Let's name the project modules like this: Main module (Module A) and secondary module(Module B).

Now I have to create a database for the library module(B) too and I added the database file into B assets directory because I thought that after compiling the project will be formed of one project having merged the module A and B. But the problem is that the B's database is not copied into the project assets directory.

Is there a way to tell Intellij to merge the assets directory too?

PS: I also have different resources in B's res directory and the application is working properly...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with IntelliJ. But I think this is more related to the Android SDK constraints, other than a config setting from IDE. as it is stated in the official dev guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#considerations):

> **Library projects cannot include raw assets**
>
> The tools do not support the use of raw asset files (saved in the assets/ directory) in a library project. Any asset resources used by an application must be stored in the assets/ directory of the application project itself. However, resource files saved in the res/ directory are supported.

You should not use assets folder in library project, instead, put all db files into your main project's assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA 11.1 already supports copying assets from Maven apklib dependencies and Android library modules in usual projects. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80771

Comment: It seems that you are right but the problem is that the fixed build is not released yet.. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an artifact for the project settings for that.

To do so: Right click the Module B project then choose "Open Module Settings". Select Artifacts and press `+` button to define a new one. Choose the "Other" type and for "Output Layout" select "Add copy of File".

Comment: Hi, can you explain how to do that please? Thank you!

Comment: I tried that but is not working.. do I have to do something with that artifact or I only have to do the steps described by you? Thank you.

Comment: Did you select the database file for that "Add copy of file"? Do that for artifact and then rebuild Module B. Then the artifact should be copied to the output directory.

Comment: I did what you said and the artifact is created in my assets directory but it deletes the old one even if the file names are different..

Comment: What kind of db is that? SQLite? Can't you put the db file in some directory outside of Module A/B?

Comment: The db is a SQLite database file and moving the database outside of assets is not an option for me, Thank you